# Возможно ли отделить Header от DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Мне хотелось бы узнать, возможно ли отделить Header от DataGrid. То есть верхнюю панель с колонками в одном объекте Border, а саму таблицу сделать внутри другого объекта Border, найти решения не смог и пытался привязать хедер одной таблицы к другой таблице без хедера, но вроде как это невозможно в WPF. Если кратко то я имею ввиду что то подобное:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавьте пустой `DataGrid`, без каких либо стилей, в дизайнере нажмите на него ПКМ, там ищите пункт "Стиль" (или чет такое), жмите "Создать копию...", указывайте куда надо сохранять. Студия вам сгенерирует стандартный стиль данного компонента со всем всем всем необходимым, в нем ищите заголовки и декорируйте как хотите.

Comment: Тут нету стиля или чего подобного https://prnt.sc/WNyGbzBpDLsz

Comment: Шаблон, могли потыкать и догадаться сами...